# Use Firebase auth cookie in third server

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, cookies, web-applications, firebase-authentication

I have a web application that deployed on Firebase Hosting and uses Firebase Authentication.

I also have a backend server, deployed on Google App Engine, that serve this app.
How can I get the Firebase-UID cookie in the backend server to validate the user?

I don't want to enforce the app to add the cookie content as a parameter for each request.

Comment: You'll send the cookie from the client to the server in whatever way you see fit, and then on the server [verify the session cookie with the admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies#verify_session_cookie_and_check_permissions). That is the only way to validate that the request came from the actual user.

Answer (score 1):

When I used the Google Identity Toolkit (merged into the Firebase Authentication since) it took a pretty long time to get an authentication token check done, so I didn't want to do it for each and every backend request.

So what I did was to perform it (typically) once per user session and, upon successful verification, create a unique memcache entry for the user and place its key in the user session info. So for subsequent requests for the same session I'd only check if the session info contains the memcache key and, if so, check if the corresponding memcache entry exists - a memcache key lookup is a lot faster than a token verification. The only thing needed to complete the picture is deletion of the memcache entry whenever the user logs out. If you want you can also enforce a token recheck after a certain amount of time - simply by setting the memcache entry's expiration time.

Note: the memcache entry can disappear anytime, which would require another token verification even if the user didn't log out - so multiple times per session. But in my case it was a rare enough occurrence.